# Keycloak ACR Token Generation

Tags: keycloak

I am currently working with Keycloak version 21.0.2 and I want to implement an authentication flow based on the importance of the resource being accessed. Imagine I have two primary flows: one based on passwords (with ACR=1), and another based on one-time password (OTP) (with ACR=2).  I want to create an API that dynamically generates tokens according to the resource being accessed. In practical terms, when the API is called with a username and password, it should generate a token with ACR 1, whereas when it is called with a username and OTP, it should generate a token with ACR 2. Consequently, clients can ascertain a user's access privileges to the resource based on the provided ACR value.

However, I face a challenge: I want this process to be solely API-driven, without requiring any user interface interaction. This presents a challenge as Keycloak's step-up authentication typically utilizes an authorization endpoint (/protocol/openid-connect/auth?...) that redirects to a browser, which is not API-only solution.